# Bash/aws-auth: how to pass parameter value in order to pass multiple step directly

Tags: bash, aws-authorizer

to refresh aws profile credential everyday, I have to launch aws cli commande and interactive like following:

```
$ ./aws-auth connect  --api-key xxx--matricule xxx --password 'xxx' --renew

=======================================================================
=                     aws-auth connect                                =
=======================================================================
There are more than one role that can be assumed.
Please choose the role you would like to assume:
[ 0] arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-xxx
[ 1] arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-xxx
[ 2] arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-xxx
[ 3] arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-xxx
[ 4] arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-xxx

Selection : 4  // enter value
Selected role : arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/role-xxx
AWS profile name (xxx) : xxx   // enter value
Selected AWS profile name : xxx
----------------------------------------------------------------
Success !
```

Is it possible to pass default value for two interactive steps to make the command run and finish without stop? or for aws-auth, is it possible to use a conf file with these 2 values and stop interactive mode?

Comment: What is the `aws-auth` program/script you're using? The first thing to do is to check its documentation.

Comment: You can try first : `{echo 4; echo xxx; } | ./aws-auth ...` If it does not work, try to use `expect`.